# Generate all Binary Combinations C++

Tags: c++, binary

I want to write a program that you give an input (number of digits n) and you get as an output a vector of all possible binary grey code generated.

For example,

```
if n=2, results should be:
V= {00, 01, 10,11}
```

Actually I am interested in having them bit by bit and not whole integer. Meaning I want to have a 2 D array of integers where I have each word in rows and bits (as int) in cols

Comment: Why don't you give it a shot and if you get stuck ask show us your code for help

Comment: You mean "Gray code", right? It's `{00, 01, 11, 10}` then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Gray code of `num` is `(num>>1) ^ num`. Go through all numbers of the `0..2^N-1` range, and compute their Gray code representation using this simple formula.

**EDIT** Another hint: the simplest way to convert an integer to binary is using `bitset`:

```
bitset<N>((num>>1) ^ num).to_string()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, actually I am interested in having them bit by bit and not whole integer. Meaning I want to have a 2 D array of integers where I have each word in rows and bits (as int) in cols

Comment: @shaklasah A added the second hint.

Answer (score 2):

The set V equals { 0, ..., 2^n-1 }. Just compute this set.

Comment: Thanks for answering, actually I am interested in having them bit by bit and not whole integer. Meaning I want to have a 2 D array of integers where I have each word in rows and bits (as int) in cols